# Python Draw a line with gradient where one color is transparent

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib

I have searched through OpenCV, matplotlib, color maps, and other posts about drawing on an image with transparencies. I have not found a way to draw a line that has a gradient that goes from one color to a transparent color.

For example, this image is close to what I mean, however, the black portion is not transparent. I need the two lines without the box around the intersection.

[image: Example Image]

Is there a package that can handle gradients with a fully transparent color like this? I've been using Python 3 and OpenCV 3, but, any other package that can accomplish this would be fine. Thank you.

Comment: How did you draw those lines? Or do you just want to remove the box for this image alone?

Comment: This was just drawn in an office package to try and represent what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for some alpha blending.

```
# Define line params
x = img.shape[1] // 2
w = 10

# Construct line
line = np.zeros_like(img)
line[:, (x-w):(x+w+1)] = (0, 255, 255)

# Construct line alpha mask
alpha = np.zeros_like(img, np.float32)
alpha[:, (x-w):x, :]   = np.repeat(np.arange(1, w+1    )[:, np.newaxis] / (w+1), 3, axis=1)
alpha[:, x:(x+w+1), :] = np.repeat(np.arange(w+1, 0, -1)[:, np.newaxis] / (w+1), 3, axis=1)

# Blend into img
img = ((1-alpha) * img + alpha * line).astype(img.dtype)
```

Comment: Ok, this gives me a vertical line just like I need! Now, my only question is, if I have several lines intersecting each other, will they 'overlay' without distorting each other? I'm interested in the intersection points of the lines.

Comment: What is "distortion"? What kind of blending are you looking for? (overlay, additive, ...) In this case, an alpha value of 1 means 100% of the line is taken.

Comment: Distortion is probably the wrong word. I would like them to overlay with the partially transparent parts from both lines being visible (meaning without one line completely blocking the other)

Comment: This does that... visually. Though you'll have to be more precise about what you want (for what application?). For instance, `0.2 * 0.8 + 0.8 * 1 = 0.96`. Some "transparency" is preserved.

Comment: In OpenCV my line goes from one point to another (using standard x,y coordinates). Is there a quick way to translate that to a numpy array? The way you wrote this changes the array elements directly.

Comment: Draw your line onto `line`. Also draw your line onto `alpha` with the correct intensity (in this case, I keep it between 0 and 1, but you could change the scaling to 0 to 255).

Comment: i'm sorry but I'm not figuring out how to do that. This is my code:
`cv2.line(line,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,204,204), thickness=anlysWdth,lineType=4)`
x1,y1 etc are just end points (Eg x1: 1580 y1: -592 x2: -45 y2: 2223)

Comment: What does `lineType=4` look like? (Too busy to search through documentation for this.)

Comment: Type of the line:

8 (or omitted) - 8-connected line.
4 - 4-connected line.
CV_AA - antialiased line.

I will put fresh eyes on it in the morning.